# Understanding os.fork and Queue.Queue

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, fork

I wanted to implement a simple python program using parallel execution.  It's I/O bound, so I figured threads would be appropriate (as opposed to processes).  After reading the documentation for Queue and fork, I thought something like the following might work.

```
q = Queue.Queue()

if os.fork():            # child
    while True:
        print q.get()
else:                    # parent
    [q.put(x) for x in range(10)]
```

However, the get() call never returns.  I thought it would return once the other thread executes a put() call.  Using the threading module, things behave more like I expected:

```
q = Queue.Queue()

def consume(q):
    while True:
        print q.get()

worker = threading.Thread (target=consume, args=(q,))
worker.start()

[q.put(x) for x in range(10)]
```

I just don't understand why the fork approach doesn't do the same thing.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The POSIX [`fork`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/fork.html) system call creates a new *process*, rather than a new *thread* inside the same adress space:

> The fork() function shall create a new process. The new process (child
>   process) shall be an exact copy of the calling process (parent
>   process) except as detailed below: [...]

So the `Queue` is duplicated in your first example, rather than shared between the parent and child.

You can use [`multiprocessing.Queue`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) instead or just use threads like in your second example :)

By the way, using list comprehensions just for side effects [isn't good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects) for several reasons. You should use a `for` loop instead:

```
for x in range(10): q.put(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

To share the data between unrelated processes, you can use named pipes. Through the os.open() funcion..
http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.open. You can simply name a pipe as named_pipe='my_pipe' and in a different python programs use os.open(named_pipe, ), where mode is WRONLY and so on. After that you'll make a FIFO to write into the pipe. Don't forget to close the pipe and catch exceptions..

Answer (score 0):

Fork creates a new process. The child and parent processes do not share the same Queue: that's why the elements put by the parent process cannot be retrieved by the child.